# taking a programmatically created tablelayout screenshot crashes app

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I have created a tablelayout programmatically with data fetched from server and have a actionbar button which is used to share the whole tablelayout as a image on installed apps. But it crashes the app with OOM Exception. The TableLayout Contains only text with some drawable layouts for look and feel and about 800 Rows

**Activity.xml**

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/webview"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
       <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true">
                <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:orientation="horizontal" >
                      <TableLayout
                         android:id="@+id/tblLayout"
                         android:stretchColumns="*"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

**Java Code On Action Bar Button**

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    tblLayout.getWidth(),
    tblLayout.getHeight(),
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
tblLayout.draw(c);

Random ran = new Random();
int filename = ran.nextInt();
bitmap = addWaterMark(bitmap);
saveBitmap(bitmap, "" + filename);

private Bitmap addWaterMark(Bitmap src) {
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    //Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

    Bitmap waterMark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_logo_full);
    waterMark=waterMark.createScaledBitmap(waterMark,150,30,false);

    //waterMark.setHeight(30);
    //For Right Bottom
    //canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap , canvas.getWidth()-bitmap.getWidth() , canvas.getHeight()-bitmap.getHeight() , paint);

    w=w/2;
    int watermark_width=waterMark.getWidth()/2;

    canvas.drawBitmap(waterMark,(w-watermark_width), 10, null);
    return result;
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,String filename) {
    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/"+filename+".png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        Log.e("Screenshot", "saved successfully");

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

I tried changing **Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888** to **Bitmap.Config.RGB_565** it works but the image having the text is like below image:

## [image: image share on whatsapp]]

When Sharing on other apps it is displayed properly like when attaching in an email displays properly.

Added

> android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

and

> android:largeHeap="true"

in AndroidManifest too but same result

Comment: You don't really need to create the `result` `Bitmap`, do you? Just draw the watermark on `src`.

Comment: Try recycling your src Bitmaps after your with them.

Comment: @NaveenDissanayake but the error is on the first step where I'm creating the bitmap i.e                                                                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    tblLayout.getWidth(),
    tblLayout.getHeight(),
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Comment: Oh dude! Your image is way too big. 800 rows come down to a huge number of pixels. You may have to increase the heap size of your app.

Comment: @NaveenDissanayake yes I knew it so added the android:hardwareAccelerated="false" and android:largeHeap="true" but same result

Comment: @NaveenDissanayake for the same reason I cutted down the rows too 250 Rows but it always gives OOM Exception

Comment: @MikeM. Yes it is needed

Comment: No, it's really not. You're creating bitmap A, then creating bitmap B, drawing A onto B, and then doing nothing else with A. You can eliminate one of those.

Comment: @MikeM. Ok mike but the real problem is still the same

Comment: Yeah, I didn't say that was your only problem, but using about twice as much memory as necessary wasn't helping things.